# How Pragma UDF works?

Tags: oracle, plsql, pragma

Recently, I have read about UDF Pragma optimization method in Oracle Database 12.

I'm very interested in how exactly it works. I've only found very short description in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/udf_pragma.htm#LNPLS1851).

As I understand, every Pragma in PL/SQL is some kind of compiler directive (I could be wrong here) similar to [C++ Pragma Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=vs-2017).

Maybe someone can explain to me in more details (or provide links :) ) how the internal mechanism of UDF Pragma works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internals are not made available to us, but essentially the pragma is an instruction to the compiler to focus on reducing the cost of the PL/SQL => SQL context switch overhead. If I had to hypothesise I would say that it takes advantage of a different 12c feature which allow PL/SQL directly within a CTE (common table expression), e.g.:

```
WITH 
  function myfunction(x int) return int as
  begin
    ...
    return ...
  end;
select myfunction(col) from my_table
```

PL/SQL functions coded like the above exist solely for the duration of the SQL execution and also execute with improved performance characteristics over that of standalone functions. So I suspect the UDF pragma allows invocation of a standalone function via the same code path as the inline example above.

(But all just hypothesis on my part)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Connor, do you know what the acronym “UDF” stands for?

Comment: I think its: user defined function, in respect to, "a function to be run under SQL as per a delivered SQL function but this one is user defined"